# How to find the maximum size of an object in a binary tree?

Tags: c, tree, find, size, binary-tree

I have a binary tree data structure with the following footprint. I am using C. 
Node is a struct containing

```
Node* left

Node* right

int key;

VECTOR data;
```

The tree is balanced by the keys (e.g. the node left of the current one has a lower key value) , not the data. I want to find the node with the largest vector. There is a function get_size(data), but I don't know how to recursively call a function to get the maximum vector size in the whole tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something along the lines of

```
int find_max_data_size( Node * p ) {

  if( !p ) return 0;

  int const left_size = find_max_data_size( p->left );
  int const right_size = find_max_data_size( p->right );
  int const my_size = get_size( p->data );

  return max( left_size, right_size, my_size );
}
```

and call `find_max_data_size( root )`;

Comment: I saw this algorithm somewhere else, but I assumed it wouldn't work. I saw it done with returning -1 if the current node is NULL, do I want to return 0 in that case, or is -1 correct. Thanks bud.

Comment: @user3546030: To me, the size is 0 in two cases: (1) NULL node, or (2) non-NULL node with empty data. I don't see when -1 is appropriate.

Comment: Ok thanks. Are you sure that this algorithm would work, because testing it I'm not getting the correct numbers. It's entirely possible I screwed something else up because this is a small part to a huge project. I am printing out the max in the function and then printing out the max final. The printf in the functions do not add up to the total things I put into the tree. Is it my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
void walk(NODE_T *I__node, size_t *maxVectorSize) 
   {   
   if(I__node) 
      {
      size_t dataSize;

      dataSize = get_size(I__node->data, maxVectorSize);
      if(dataSize > *maxVectorSize)
         *maxVectorSize = dataSize;

      walk(I__node->left, maxVectorSize);
      walk(I__node->right, maxVectorSize);
      }

   return;
   }
```

Comment: If i print the size in-between the walk calls, I get different sizes than the answer above. Any ideas?